# Глагольное и именное предложения

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, лексика

Есть ли в русском языке глагольное предложение , и чем оно отличается от именного предложения по составу и по смыслу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, речь идёт об односоставных предложениях. В современном русском языке существуют два основных типа односоставных предложений -глагольные и именные. В глагольных односоставных предложениях утверждается независимый признак (действие): В саду пели; Вам придется подождать; Быть грозе великой и т.п. В именных (субстантивных) односоставных предложениях утверждается или отрицается бытие предмета: Полночь; Зима. и т.п.

В глагольных односоставных предложениях в роли главного члена могут выступать все основные спрягаемые формы и инфинитив. В именных предложениях в позиции главного члена употребляется лишь существительное (или субстантивированное слово) в именительном или родительном падеже.